# jQuery Contention issue

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have a webpage where there are lot of jQuery related scripts are loaded. I am including another script to the page along with the existing scripts.

The below script works fine as excepted.

```
    $(".mytext").emoticons();
```

But when I use the same script inside setInterval, other jquery related stuffs are not working.

```
  $(function() {
      setInterval(function() { $(".mytext").emoticons() }, 5 * 1000);
  });
```

Am I missing anything? Please let me know if I need to provide any other information. I am sure what information I can provide for this of vague(yeah, I know) but have no idea on this.

EDIT: The above mentioned emoticons() is a jquery plugin from http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~skreft/emoticon/

Comment: What's the definition for .emoticons()?

Comment: emoticons is from the link http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~skreft/emoticon/

Answer (score 0):

why are you calling the function with jquery? like $(function()...);
try to set the interval in the global namespace without jquery wrapping it

```
setInterval(function() { $(".mytext").emoticons() }, 5 * 1000);
```

or put it in an anonymous function:

```
(function(){
    setInterval(function() { $(".mytext").emoticons() }, 5 * 1000);
})();
```

and watch out, perhaps you are starting setInterval before your emoticons script is loaded

Comment: I don't believe it will work if its used without jquery wrapping. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: why not? setInterval is a native js-function.